# How to set headers Spring oauth AccessTokenRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to call setHeaders method of org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenRequest and not able to do it.

Class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenRequest.java) declares

```
void setHeaders(Map<? extends String, ? extends List<String>> headers);
```

Questions:

1. Since String is a final class in java, what purpose does it solve to say "? extends String" in the declaration.
2. How do I create my map and put entry in it. I have tried following

   ```
   final Map<? extends String, ? extends List<String>> headers = accTknReq.getHeaders();
   final List<String> lst1 = headers.get("MyHeader");
   final ArrayList<String> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
   headers.put("MyHeader", lst1);
   headers.put("MyHeader", lst2);
   ```

In both cases I get following compiler error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project : Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR] :[33,24] method put in interface java.util.Map cannot be applied to given types;
>   [ERROR] required: capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.String,capture#2 of ? extends java.util.List
>   [ERROR] found: java.lang.String,java.util.List

Answer (score 3):

For your second question, you can try something like the following to set headers.

```
final Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<>(accTknReq.getHeaders());
```

Comment: srkavin, Thank you. This helped me to continue.